# pandas fill cells based on succession of other cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `df` with lots of missing data but essentially the same columns (originating from merging data sets). As an example, consider the following:

```
temp = pd.DataFrame({"fruit_1": ["apple", "pear", "don't want to tell", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
                     "fruit_2": [np.nan, np.nan, "don't want to tell", "apple", "don't want to tell", np.nan],
                     "fruit_3": ["apple", np.nan, "pear", "don't want to tell", np.nan, "pear"]})
```

I now want to merge them into one column; conflicts should be resolved as follows:

- np.nan always overridden with other information
- "don't want to tell" only overrides np.nan
- any other value overrides only np.nan and "don't want to tell" (i.e. keep first value).

I have tried creating a new column and using `apply` (see below).

```
temp.insert(0, "fruit", np.nan)
temp['fruit'].apply(lambda row: row["fruit"] if np.isnan(row["fruit"]) and not np.isnan(row["fruit_1"]) else np.nan) # map col
```

The code, however, produces a `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable`

Can someone tell me whether (1) this is a feasible approach in general - and if so, what my mistake is? And (2) what would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

** EDIT **
The expected output is

```
                fruit             
0               apple         
1                pear       
2                pear  
3               apple             
4  don't want to tell
5                pear
```

Comment: Please share the expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `ffill` and additional `np.where`

```
s=temp.mask(temp=="don't want to tell").bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
s=np.where((temp=="don't want to tell").any(1)&s.isnull(),"don't want to tell",s)
s
Out[17]: 
array(['apple', 'pear', 'pear', 'apple', "don't want to tell", 'pear'],
      dtype=object)
temp['New']=s
temp
Out[19]: 
              fruit_1  ...                 New
0               apple  ...               apple
1                pear  ...                pear
2  don't want to tell  ...                pear
3                 NaN  ...               apple
4                 NaN  ...  don't want to tell
5                 NaN  ...                pear
[6 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Thank you. This looks like it does what I want; however, to fully understand the code and adapt it to what I want to apply it on, could you clarify the mask assignment. In particular, I'm not entirely sure about the `.iloc` - I'm trying to apply this to a data frame with around 8-10 columns (i.e. `fruit_1` through `fruit_8`) and am trying to adapt it.
Thanks a ton!

Comment: @IvoB. mask is to make don't want to tell to nan , we first consider them are same , then we check the result , if the result is nan, we need to check the original df have don't want to tell or not , if they have we need to change nan to that

Comment: as OP indicates to keep *first value*, should we use `bfill(1)` instead?

Comment: @QuangHoang ummmm yes

Comment: thanks a ton @QuangHoang and @WeNYoBen. What exactly is the function of `.iloc` then? The rest seems to make sense to me.

Comment: @IvoB. select the column by position